# Transferred Ownership of Git repo -- Now Netbeans project kinda broken

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I had:

- A github repo
- A netbeans project that referenced that repo

Then I transferred ownership of the repo from my personal github account to my organization's github account.

Now my Netbeans project wants to pull/push to the old repo that is now missing.

So, How do I:

1. Remove the reference to the old repo so that it never "suggests" this non-working option
2. Change the default repo so that it points to the correct repo (i.e. I don't want to repeatedly change the pull/push target)

FYI -- I've looked through the documentation and browsed the menu options pretty extensively.

Comment: How did you do the transfer?

Comment: @Atropo -- Go to "Settings" for a project on my personal github account (where you can delete a project).  Select the transfer ownership option, provide some other Github account id, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you updated the config in your Git repository? I think you may need to do that. You need to edit it and replace your username with your organization's in the `url` under `[remote "origin"]`:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@github.com/[your username]/[project name].git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

In Git Bash:

```
cd [your repository]
vim .git/config
```

I'm not sure exactly how Netbeans gets information about your repository, but I would guess it's from the config file. Hope that helps.

Comment: This definitely looks promising -- I'll check it out after lunch (I too was wondering where netbeans got this info)

Comment: This is a winner.  Thank you very much.